# Why iperf measurements for UDP maximum bandwidth are always the same?

Tags: performance, networking, tcp, udp, measurement

I am using iperf tool to measure maximum bandwidth between two nodes via UDP protocol. On server side I use:

```
./iperf -s -u
```

On client side I use:

```
./iperf -c <server ip> -u
```

For each time (set by `-t [time]` switch) I choose, no matter how many times I run the test, I get the same result. For TCP it is slightly different each time (which is ok, I guess). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

iperf for udp has a default bandwidth limit. Override it with the "-b" flag and see what you get.